# What does => do in Ada

Tags: operators, ada

I am debuggin some Ada code, and have come across a loop in which there are several lines containing the operator: `=>`. I have not come across this before, and a quick Google hasn't really been much help in finding out what it does... Can anyone help me here?

For example, in the loop, there are lines such as:

```
time => data.time;
distance => data.distance;
```

Is this assigning the value of the variables on the right hand side to the ones on the left- so that the ones on the left are now equal to the ones on the right, or maybe assigning the memory addresses of the variables on the left, so that they point to the location of the variables on the right?

Any help would be much appreciated.

**Edited to show surrounding code (04/02/2015 @ 1700)**

So, a fuller example of somewhere that `=>` is used would be:

```
if data.IASType /= Types.TOA and data.IASType /= Types.RNG then
  -- Calculate positionOfTarget using the laterRelativeTime
  ...
  SteeringUtilities.calculateApproachData
    (...
     time => data.time,
     distance => data.distance,
end if;
```

Apologies- just realised I miss quoted the two lines earlier by putting `;` at the end of the lines rather than `,`.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the loop. Most likely, it has something to do with an [aggregate](http://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/12rm/html/RM-4-3-1.html) assignment within the loop. But it's impossible for us to guess without more context. And the semicolons looks like syntax errors.

Comment: Another possibility is a subprogram call with call-by-value semantics. Anyway, more context is needed here.

Comment: ah, yes. [Named association](http://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/12rm/html/RM-6-4.html#I3454)

Comment: @someone2088 Basically, provide the lines of code immediately surrounding the ones you listed so we can see the context in which they appear.

Comment: This is Named Parameter Association as @egilhh first suggested.

Comment: @AnsgarEsztermann It has nothing to do with "call-by-value".  This notation can be used for any subprogram call, whether the parameters are passed by value or by reference.

Comment: @ajb: You're right. I meant named parameters.

Answer (score 4):

`=>` is not an "operator".  It's a syntax element whose most common purpose is to let you specify a list of things (such as parameters to a subprogram call) by showing what each item in the list means, instead of simply listing them in order.  For example, one of the `Put_Line` procedures is defined like this:

```
procedure Put_Line(File : in  File_Type; Item : in String);
```

When you call it, the following calls are all equivalent:

```
Put_Line(My_File, "Hello, world");
Put_Line(File => My_File, Item => "Hello, world");
Put_Line(Item => "Hello, world", File => My_File);
```

The syntax is used for many other things, such as lists of discriminants, parameters in a generic instantiation, parameters to a pragma, etc.  It's also used for record and array aggregates--for array aggregates, you can have an index, multiple indexes, ranges of indexes, or `others` on the left side of `=>`.